# How can I add applications of my choice to Ubuntu Installation image?

Tags: software-installation, iso, persistence

So, I tried searching google for this but did not really get an answer to.

What I am looking for is adding applications to a Ubuntu Installation image. I know I can create a live USB with persistence and install applications on it which will persist but I don't know if, when I use that USB to install Ubuntu on the machine, these custom installed applications will also be a part of the new system.

If not, how do I go about doing this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Preseed file. See https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/armhf/apbs01.html

Comment: Rinzwind's answer works: http://askubuntu.com/a/49679/

Comment: Haven't tested the solution but looks like this is exactly what I required. Marked my question duplicate myself. Thanks everyone.